# How to invert an integral equation

Tags: equation-solving, inverse

There have been numerous times when I've needed to invert an integral equation, i.e. I have something like
$$f(x) = g_1(x)\int_{0}^x g_2(x') dx'$$
for arbitrary functions $g_1$ and $g_2$, and I would like to find $x$ for a given $f$.  The way I've gotten around this is just making some sort of table of f(x) and x with spacing up to some required precision.  Is there a more efficient method of doing it (numerically or analytically)?

When I try to use `NSolve[ f(x) == a, x ]` mathematica complains `NIntegrate::nlim: x = x is not a valid limit of integration.`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My interpretation of the question is that you want to find $x$ for given $f$, $g_2$ and $g_1$. Then just define $F=f/g_1$ and differentiate with respect to $x$ on both sides:

$\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=g_2(x)$

Now solve this equation for $x$. There's no integration involved.

Comment: Just implemented this and it works well.  Using a simple finite-difference routine to calculate the derivative of 'F' is computationally trivial compared to the iterative numerical integrations.

Comment: I tried to implement this using `ND` and `FindRoot`, but I am getting strange problems. Maybe I need to ask a separate question.

Comment: Here is the separate question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57435/bug-in-paralleltable-after-evaluating-another-function-using-ndsolve-and-findroo

Answer (score 5):

Answering your comment:

```
f[x_?NumericQ] := f[x] = g1[x] NIntegrate[g2[t], {t, 0, x}];
g1[x_] := Sin[x]; g2[x_] := Cos[x];
k = FindRoot[f[x] == Pi/9, {x, 1}]
Pi/9 - f[x] /. k[[1]]
(*
->
{x -> 0.632072}
-5.55112*10^-17
*)
```

Comment: Thanks @belisarius, but my g2 can't be integrated numerically.  I.E. I have something like `f[x_]:=g1[x]*NIntegrate[g2[t],{t,0,x}]' and I get the above error