# Issue in ParallelTable after evaluating another function using NDSolve and FindRoot. What is wrong with this inverse?

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, parallelization, interpolation, broken-code

I am trying to find the inverse of a function which is defined through `NDSolve` and `NIntegrate`.

The question is pretty similar to [How to invert an integral equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/how-to-invert-an-integral-equation). Just that in my case $g_1(x)=1$ and $g_2(x)$ is the solution of an NDSolve.

Following the first answer https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4604/6138, I tried to implement this using `NDSolve` and `FindRoot`, but I get an error message and I don't understand where it comes from.

The bug appears in the fact that if I don't evaluate the inverse function, there is no problem with ParallelTable or Table. After evaluating the inverse function, ParallelTable (but not Table) shows me the same error message. 
I would also like to know why FindRoot doesn't work in this case.

Below is my minimal working code and some comments:

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"]
kvalues = {0.01,0.1,0.5,1.0,2.0};
tini = -Log[100]; 
tfin = 0;
timeGrid = Range[tini,tfin,(tfin-tini)/10];
fSpace[min_, max_, steps_, f_: Log] :=
  InverseFunction[f] /@ Range[f @ min, f @ max, (f @ max - f @ min)/(steps -1)]
kin = 0.00072427;
kfin = 2.159;
klogGrid = fSpace[kin, kfin, 10];

funcA = 
  NDSolveValue[{
    D[f[t, k], t] + f[t, k]^2 + (1 - t)*f[t, k] == 3/2*(1 + k^2), 
    f[tini, k] == 1}, 
    f, {t, tini, tfin}, {k, kin, kfin}]

funcB[t_?NumericQ, k_] := 
  funcB[t, k] = Exp[NIntegrate[funcA[et,k], {et, tini,t}]]

funcD[td_, kd_] := ND[Log[funcB[tt, kd]], tt, td]
```

Now a simple evaluation with `ParallelTable`:

```
BTable = ParallelTable[{{tt, kk}, funcB[tt, kk]}, {tt, timeGrid}, {kk,
klogGrid}]
```

The output is (shortened):

> {{{-Log[100], 0.00072427}, 1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.00176173}, 
>     1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.00428528}, 1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.0104236}, 
>     1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.0253546}, 1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.0616732}, 
>     1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.150015}, 1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.3649}, 
>     1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.887592}, 1.}, {{-Log[100], 2.159}, 1.}...

Now if I try:

```
inverseN = FindRoot[funcD[tt, kk] == funcA[tt, kk], {tt, -1}]
```

I get:

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand InterpolatingFunction[{{-4.60517,0.},{0.00072427,2.159}},{4,5,1,{54,25},{4,5},0,0,0,0,Automatic,{},{},False},{<<1>>},{Developer`PackedArrayForm,{<<1>>},{1.,-5.10517,1.,-5.09284,1.,-5.05626,1.,-4.99541,1.,-4.9103,1.,-4.80093,1.,-4.6673,1.,-4.5094,1.,-4.32725,1.,-4.12083,1.,-3.89015,1.,<<5>>,1.,-2.72483,1.,-2.37285,1.,-1.99661,1.,-1.5961,1.,-1.17133,1.,-0.722307,1.,-0.249018,1.,0.248533,1.,0.770344,1.,1.31642,1.,1.88675,<<2650>>}},{Automatic,Automatic}][<<1>>] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-Log[100],-4.60186}}. >>

The same thing happens if I use the inverse function method suggested in the *Mathematica* documentation of [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html):

```
inv[f_, s_] := Function[{t}, s /. FindRoot[f - t, {s, -2}]]
fInverse = inv[funcB[tt, kk], tt]
```

Now the bug: If I know evaluate again ParallelTable, I get the same above error message:

```
BTable = ParallelTable[{{tt, kk}, funcB[tt, kk]}, {tt, timeGrid}, {kk,
klogGrid}]
```

...

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand InterpolatingFunction[{{-4.60517,0.},{0.00072427,2.159}},....Automatic}][<<1>>] has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-Log[100],-4.60186}}. >>

But after the error messages I get the correct output from above.

Nevertheless, with `Table` nothing bad happens:

```
Table[{{tt, kk}, funcB[tt, kk]}, {tt, timeGrid}, {kk, klogGrid}]
```

> {{{{-Log[100], 0.00072427}, 1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.00176173}, 
>      1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.00428528}, 1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.0104236}, 
>      1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.0253546}, 1.}, {{-Log[100], 0.0616732}, 1.},....

I hope you can reproduce this bug and by the way help me with finding the inverse function.

I tried this in *Mathematica* 10.0 and 9.0

Comment: Try `funcB[t_?NumericQ, k_] := funcB[t, k] = Exp[NIntegrate[funcA[et,k], {et, tini,t}]]`

Comment: That's what I already have, isn't it?

Comment: No, not in your post. You have `funcB[t_?NumericQ, k_] := funcB[t?NumericQ, k] = Exp[NIntegrate[funcA[et, k], {et, tini, t}]]`. The `t?NumericQ` is bad.

Comment: Ok thanks! I'll try that. Maybe that causes the strange behaviour without warnings.

Comment: @m_goldberg I tried that and I still get the same result. Maybe I should rephrase the question to make it more accesible and understandable. The basic problem is that when I run this code without calling the inverse functions, I get no error messages at all. If I run the inverse function, I get the error message there and also when calling ParallelTable. Clearing the functions A and B doesn't help anymore then.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reasons for the change in the behavior of `ParallelTable` are subtle.  The main source of the problem is that in `funcB`, the argument `k_` is not protected with `?NumericQ` like this:

```
funcB[t_?NumericQ, k_?NumericQ] := (* a solution *)
 funcB[t, k] = Exp[NIntegrate[funcA[et, k], {et, tini, t}]]
```

But more on that later.  The problem does not appear in the first `ParallelTable`, but the trap is set by executing

```
inverseN = FindRoot[funcD[tt, kk] == funcA[tt, kk], {tt, -1}]
```

I will explain how the trap is set later.  First observe that this command naturally produces error messages because `tt` is numeric but `kk` is not.  Thus the `NIntegrate` is ultimately invoked with a nonnumeric integrand when `funcD` calls `funcB`.  If `kd_` or `k_` were protected with `?NumericQ`, only `FindRoot` would complain and evaluation would never reach `NIntegrate`.

The key to the trap is that evaluation reaches `funcB`, which memoizes its evaluation.  Since the argument `k_` is the symbol `kk`, `NIntegrate` complains and returns unevaluated.  This unevaluated `NIntegrate` is saved in `funcB[tt, kk]`.

```
?funcB
```

> ```
> Global`funcB
> ```

```
(*
  funcB[-1.,kk] = E^NIntegrate[funcA[et, kk], {et, tini, -1.}]
  ...
  funcB[t_?NumericQ, k_] := funcB[t, k] = Exp[NIntegrate[...
*)
```

On the face of it, this should be no problem since `ParallelTable` substitutes numeric, not symbolic, values for `kk`.  Ah, but the surprise is that is not where the problem arises.  **The problem arises from distributing the definitions!**  `ParallelTable` distributes definitions before it begins tabulating.

If the definitions above are evaluated on the parallel kernels, the `NIntegrate` will be evaluated, which will give errors since `kk` is a symbol.  The following will show it.

```
(* Evaluate the OP's definitions *)
inverseN = FindRoot[funcD[tt, kk] == funcA[tt, kk], {tt, -1}]
(* abort the above after the NIntegrate::inumr messages *)

DistributeDefinitions[funcB]
```

> NIntegrate::inumr: The integrand <<1>> has evaluated to non-numerical values for all sampling points in the region with boundaries {{-Log[100], -4.60186}}. >>
>   ...

For the sake of curiosity, the following definition works, which shows the difference between `Set` and `SetDelayed`:

```
funcB[t_?NumericQ, k_] := 
  funcB[t, k] := Evaluate@Exp[NIntegrate[funcA[et, k], {et, tini, t}]]
```

The definition given at the beginning is the best one to use.  It would be good to do something similar with `funcD` and any other function which does not make sense on nonnumeric inputs.

```
funcD[td_?NumericQ, kd_?NumericQ] := ND[Log[funcB[tt, kd]], tt, td]
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to explain carefully the problem, I would have never found this subtlety. Should I change the title of my answer and remove the word bug?

Comment: @Santi You're welcome.  I suppose "bug" is misleading.  Something like "problem" or "issue" might seem more appropriate.