# A peculiar behavior of `ParametricFunction`

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving, parametric-functions

I am trying to use `ParametricNDSolve` to find a desired value for a parameter in an ODE, and the output seems to misbehave.

First, consider the following example given in the [documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html.en#:%7E:text=%C2%A0(10)-,Parameter%20Sweeps,-(4)):

```
sol1 = ParametricNDSolve[{x''[t] - x'[t] + x[t] == 0, x[0] == 1, x'[0] == s}, x, {t, 0, 30}, {s}]
(* ::Output:: *) (*
{x -> ParametricFunction[ <> ]}
*)
root1 = FindRoot[Evaluate[x[s][10] /. sol1], {s, 6}]
(* ::Output:: *) (*
{s -> 1.40296}
*)
```

Secondly, my equation with the `Automatic`ally chosen method:

```
sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[{X'[t] == t + (Sqrt[3] / Pi) Log[a/(1 - a)] Abs[t X[t]] - X[t], X[0] == 1}, {X}, {t, 0, 2}, a]
(* ::Output:: *) (*
{x -> ParametricFunction[ <> ]}
*)

root2 = FindRoot[Evaluate[X[a][2] /. sol2] == 3, {a, .5}]
(* ::Output:: *) (*
[!] InterpolatingFunction: Input {2} lies outside the range of data... (InterpolatingFunction::dmval)
{a -> 0.812787}
*)
```

In which I don't understand how the range is exceeded. Furthermore, specifying a method in the call yields:

```
sol3 = = ParametricNDSolve[{X'[t] == t + (Sqrt[3] / Pi) Log[a/(1 - a)] Abs[t X[t]] - X[t], X[0] == 1}, {X}, {t, 0, 2}, a, Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> "ExplicitEuler"}]
(* ::Output:: *) (*
{x -> ParametricFunction[ <> ]}
*)

X[.7][2] /. sol3
(* ::Output:: *) (*
2.01701
*)

root3 = FindRoot[Evaluate[X[a][2] /. sol3] == 3, {a, .5}]
(* ::Output:: *) (*
[!] ParametricNDSolve: Encountered invalid NDSolve`SensitivityMethod method data object at point t=0.` (ParametricNDSolve::mdata)
[!] FindRoot: At {a}={0.5}, function value {-3+ParametricFunction[1,Internal`Bag[<1>],1,1,False,{{a$71966},<<5>>,{0}},{NDSolve`base$71973,NDSolve`NDSolveParametricFunction[0,{ParametricNDSolve,Internal`Bag[<2>],None,ParametricNDSolve},{{{<<9>>},{<<9>>}},{0,{<<3>>},{<<2>>},{<<3>>}},None,{{<<7>>},{<<1>>},None,{}}},{X},<<4>>,{Cache->True,CacheTableLength->19,CacheTableWidth->7,CacheKeyMaxBytes->1000000,CacheResultMaxBytes->1000000,KeyComparison->None,ResultComparison->LessEqual},{},<<1>>]}][0.5][2]} is not a {1} dimensional list of numbers  (FindRoot::nlnum)
{a -> 0.5}
*)

X[.7][2] /. sol3
(* ::Output:: *) (*
ParametricFunction[ <> ][0.7][2]
*)
```

Note that `t=2` is indeed in the interpolation range, and the call to the `ParametricFunction` instance fails after the unsuccessful `FindRoot` run.

How to understand this behavior, and is there a current workaround if it's a bug?

---

Related:

1. [ParametricFunction from ParametricNDSolveValue changes when evaluated?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/198132/72025)
2. [Vector ParametricNDSolve and FindRoot interaction](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199631/72025)
3. [Issue in ParallelTable after evaluating another function using NDSolve and FindRoot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/57435/72025)

Comment: In the first link, [@Carl Woll](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/45431/carl-woll)['s answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/198138/72025) suggests that there is indeed something wrong with `ParametricFunction`, however I am not sure if the behavior in the current post is of the same origin. Root solving is a large numeric topic, and I haven't  finished all the tech notes and SE QA's just yet; do be kind enough and point me to anything that I am supposed to read.

Comment: I think "Findroot"  makes a first guess using something like the tangent. This can lead to a bad first guess. Therefore, try a starting value closer to the searched root. E.g.: `FindRoot[Evaluate[X[a][2] /. sol1] == 3, {a, .7}]`

Comment: @DanielHuber This indeed yields a good root and prevents the `ParametricFunction` from being spoiled

Comment: To get a good starting value use `Plot`, i.e., `Plot[(X[a][2] - 3) /. sol3, {a, 0, 1}]` indicates the solution is in the vicinity of `0.8` Alternatively, avoid derivatives by using "FindRoot[lhs == rhs, {x, Subscript[x, 0], Subscript[x, 1]}] searches for a solution using Subscript[x, 0] and Subscript[x, 1] as the first two values of x, avoiding the use of derivatives."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Evaluated -> False`

```
Clear[sol2, root2];
sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[{X'[t] == 
    t + (Sqrt[3]/Pi) Log[a/(1 - a)] Abs[t X[t]] - X[t], 
   X[0] == 1}, {X}, {t, 0, 2}, a]
root2 = FindRoot[(X[a][2] /. sol2) == 3, {a, .5}, Evaluated -> False]
```

> `{a -> 0.812787}`

Comment: I find this indeed works. Would you explain what the option means and does? Thanks in advance

Comment: `Clear[sol];
sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == 
     t + (Sqrt[3]/Pi) Log[a/(1 - a)] Abs[t X[t]] - X[t], 
    X[0] == 1}, {X}, {t, 0, 2}, {a}];
FindRoot[Indexed[sol[a], 1][2] == 3, {a, .5}]`

Answer (score 2):

> and is there a current workaround

Some strange evaluation order? Here is a workaround

```
sol2 = ParametricNDSolve[{X'[t] == t + (Sqrt[3]/Pi) Log[a/(1 - a)] Abs[t X[t]] - X[t], 
    X[0] == 1}, {X}, {t, 0, 2}, a];
f[a_] := X[a] /. sol2
root2 = FindRoot[Evaluate[f[a][2] /. sol2] == 3, {a, .5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

No beep and no warnings and no range exceeded messages.

V 13.1 on windows 10

Screen shot. No messages.
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: v13.1 here too. Weirdly enough this doesn't seems to fix it for me. I'll clear the kernel and try again.

Comment: @Gravifer no messages/warnings for me on V 13.1 on windows 10. Yes, make sure to Quit the kernel. Added screen shot

Comment: I can now replicate your result. However, what dictates the result for me is `/.sol2` in the `FindRoot`; with this replacement no exception is thrown. I don't fully understand why this is the case yet.

Answer (score 2):

Without `Method -> {"TimeIntegration" -> "ExplicitEuler"}`  try more direct solution using `ParametricNDSolveValue`(only return X[2])

```
X3 = ParametricNDSolveValue[{X'[t] == t + (Sqrt[3]/Pi) Log[a/(1 - a)] Abs[t X[t]]- X[t], X[0] == 1}, 
X[2] , {t, 0, 2}, a  ]
root3 = FindRoot[ X3[a]   == 3, {a, 1/2 }]
(* {a -> 0.812787} *)
```

`NMinimize` evaluates without  message " Input value {2} lies outside..."

```
NMinimize[ (X3[a]  - 3)^2, a]
(*{6.10426*10^-16, {a -> 0.812787}}  *)
```

Comment: This seems to be my `sol2`? Sorry I pasted the wrong output though.

Comment: No it isn't your `sol2`

Comment: Oh sorry I glanced over the second line...